# Does 甘い蜜 have another meaning?

Tags: grammar

甘い蜜 literally means "sweet honey". But in some sentences it seems to mean something different. For example,

> 1) たまに**甘い蜜**を与えて、また暗闇に落として……。

*From time to time giving a sweet honey, but also dropping into darkness.*

> 2) 結局、**甘い蜜**を吸うのはいつだって上の連中だけ。

*After all, only they always suck a sweet honey.*

> 3) お前をそそのかし、**甘い蜜**を与え、そして最後には堕落させてやる。

*I instigate you, give you sweet honey, and in the end corrupt you.*

Well, in the last sentence it must be "give you a pleasure". Anyway, I think that 甘い蜜 must mean something pleasurable, something that makes people happy.

My question is: what is the meaning of 甘い密 in sentences like these?

Comment: I think in this context it means feeding you "sweet lies"

Comment: Hello!  I believe that I understood what Shiva was asking, so I decided to try to clarify the question and reopen.  Hopefully that's okay with everyone :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「[甘]{あま}い[蜜]{みつ}」 is seldom used to mean what it literally means --- "sweet honey".  Instead, it is generally used metaphorically to refer to instant pleasure or satisfaction that is often used as a trap or lure.  That is what the phrase means in your sentences #1 and #3.

In #2, 甘い蜜 is used for a meaning that is kind of close (but not exactly) to its literal meaning. There, it means "the sweet reward".

Answer (score 2):

甘い蜜 has two metaphorical meanings, aside from its literal meaning ("sweet honey"):

1. the negative sense: "tantalizing trap"
2. the positive sense: "sweet reward"

> 1) たまに甘い蜜を与えて、また暗闇に落として……。
>   "Slowly allure, even further into the darkness..." *(meaning 1)*
>
> 2) 結局、甘い蜜を吸うのはいつだって上の連中だけ。
>   "In the end, the rewards are always reserved for the brass." *(meaning 2)*
>
> 3) お前をそそのかし、甘い蜜を与え、そして最後には堕落させてやる。
>   "I will entice you, tempt you, and in the end, pervert you." *(meaning 1)*